# Git push plugin on TFS 2015

Tags: git, tfs-2015

I'm developing plugin for GIT commits for TFS Server 2015. 
I've copied solution with little changes from: http://almsports.net/tfs-server-side-check-in-policy-for-git-repositories/1025/. The problem is that in newest version of TFS Server dlls there are no implementations of `TeamFoundationGitRepositoryService` and therefore I'm stuck on that.

Had someone similar problem and manage to get a solution?

Comment: Did you just want to create a Server side Plugin for Git push ? What's the mainly usage of your plugin?

Comment: Yes, I want to create server side plugin. This plugin should check commit messages if they have correct format and if not not allow to save them on server side.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not any replacement. This couldn't be achieved for now. Sever-side git hooks is still on backlog, more details please refer my update answer below.

Answer (score 0):

`TeamFoundationGitRepositoryService` the namespace you mentioned is on the TFS server API.

Since it's move away from TFS2015. There is not any replacement.

One way is using a server-side git hooks, such as a commit message hook to visualize all commits. However this is still on backlog:

> **Add server-side git hooks**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/3895135-add-server-side-git-hooks

Also take a look at this similar question: [Custom checkin policy for TFS GIT](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e28dbf87-56c4-42ae-84ad-ccb18c51653a/custom-checkin-policy-for-tfs-git?forum=TFService)